# Determine whether $-7 + \frac {14} 3 - \frac {28} 9 + \frac {56} {27} + \dots$ converges or not.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, closed-form

Determine whether the series converges or not.

$$-7 + \frac {14} 3 - \frac {28} 9 +  \frac {56} {27} + \dots$$

This is the Alternating Harmonic Series but I can't see the common ratio here. Any suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: It is not the alternating harmonic series -- see if you can determine how each term is obtained from the term before.

Comment: The alternating harmonic series is $1 - \frac 1 2 + \frac 1 3 - \frac 1 4 + \frac 1 5 - \frac 1 6 + \dots$, not what you wrote.

Comment: numerator doubles each time, denominator multiplies by 3, signs alternate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One may recall that

> $$
> \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac1{1-x},\qquad |x|<1.
> $$

Then you may write your series as
$$
-7\times\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(-\frac23\right)^n.
$$ and conclude.